# Bungie API for Destiny2 user: find membershipId or bungie display name by platform nickname

Tags: rest, xbox, playstation

I am supporting an app that gets player game statistics. We have for example playstation or xbox nickname and need to find bungie membershipId.

I look code - we missuse "Destiny2/SearchDestinyPlayer" API, as it requires not playstation nickname (or xbox nickname) but full bungie name including #xxxx (# id)
https://bungie-net.github.io/#Destiny2.SearchDestinyPlayer

Looks like before in Destiny2 appeared cross-save function it was the same nickname and #id was not mandatory.

Could someone suggest another API that accepts platform (xbox or playstation) nickname?
Also maybe suggest forum dedicated to bungie API?

PS: I searched alternative sites, for example on "https://destinytracker.com/" I am able to select platform "Playstation" and enter nickname "T-rex_on_point" - it finds bungie name Brontosaurus881#6169 and also membershipId inside URL. How it does it? What API it uses?
I finally need "membershipId" id, but if I will find full bungie display name - then I am able to find "membershipId" with Destiny2/SearchDestinyPlayer" API mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

There is no ***"Other API"***. All applications uses one API which's Bungie's.

I'm assuming you're making the request using `#` in the URL which's not [UTF-8 URL encoded](https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding).

You'll need to encode the URL specifically the `#` which will be encoded to `%23`. So instead of making the request with this name `Brontosaurus881#6169` it should be like this `Brontosaurus881%236169`.

Also what language are you using? if Python then use `urllib.parse.quote("Brontosaurus881#6169")`.
If not then i suggest you looking up how to encode a URL in `x` language.

Also if you're using Python, There's a [wrapper](https://github.com/nxtlo/aiobungie) around the API that already does that for you **if** you're interested and using Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much. I understand about url enconding. I use C#, but use also helper (System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode) for url encoding.
But problem itself is that don't know #nr (6169 here). 
For example we know only xbox nickname, which is "Brontosaurus881" but user can change it, or vice versa change bungie display name.
For example we know xbox nickame = "my_xbox_nick" already and need find out bungie nick name (for example it is my_renamed_bungie_nick#1357, but we don't have it)
Our idea now is that we somewhere GUI shoud ask user to enter bungie display name.

Comment: I see. so what you’re trying to do is insert `name` and return `name#1234`? in this case you probably wanna use `SearchByGlobalNamePrefix` endpoint which basically searches for users by their display names only.